# How to print all linux users with Puppet and ruby?

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

I want to create a facter that returns all users.

```
Facter.add("sysusers") do
  setcode do
    File.readlines('/etc/passwd').each do |line|
      line.match(/^[^:]+/)[0]
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my `.pp` file I have this:

```
$users = inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar('sysusers') %>")

$users.each |String $user| {
  notify { "$user":}
}
```

This should work but the facter returns just one letter at a time.

So `notify { "$user":}` just prints:

```
Notify[r]
Notify[o]
```

And then it craches because the next letter is also "o" (two o`s in "root" and root is the first user stated in /etc/passwd).
So how can I print all the users?

**EDIT**
With the edit to:

```
Facter.add("sysusers") do
  setcode do
    File.readlines('/etc/passwd').each do |line|
      line.match(/^[^:]+/).to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Then the output is:

```
root@mymachine]# facter sysusers
[
  "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
",
  "bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/usr/bin/nologin
",
  "daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/:/usr/bin/nologin
...
...
```

So it still does not seem to work as expeced.

Answer (score 2):

This is the match you want.

```
line.match(/^[^:]+/).to_s
```

When you add [0], it is taking the first character from the string that is the user name.

EDIT

```
File.readlines('/etc/passwd').collect do |line|
        line.match(/^[^:]+/).to_s
end
```

That will collect an array which to be returned in your setcode.

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. Look at my edit above please.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing `/etc/passwd` is a clunky approach to your problem.

It's cleaner to use the [Etc module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-passwd)

```
require 'etc'
result = []
Etc.passwd { |user| result << user.name }
result
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following ruby code, which reads and prints the user names from /etc/passwd file.

```
IO.readlines("/etc/passwd").each do |val|
        user = val.split(":").first
        puts user
end
```